# Count duplicate rows in H2 database

Tags: java, sql, count, duplicates, h2

I have a H2 database with 120m rows and 4 columns with integer values only. I'm trying to count all duplicate rows.

This is the select statement:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, COUNT(*) AS dupes FROM t1 GROUP BY a, b, c, d HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

When I use this statement in a database with ~4m rows it works fine.
In a database with >4m rows it throws an ArrayOutOfBounds exception.
In a database with more than ~10m rows I get an OutOfMemoryError (Increasing Java Heap Space didn't help) or an out of physical memory error.

How can I improve the select statement? How can I make it more efficient for >10m rows and
why does it throw an ArrayOutOfBounds exception with >4m rows?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, H2 needs a lot of memory for grouped queries with many rows in result unless a compatible index for `GROUP BY` clause is present. If you don't have enough memory, you need to define such index.

```sql
CREATE INDEX T1_ABCD_IDX ON T1(A, B, C, D);
```

Such `AIOOBE` exception looks like a bug, but the workaround is the same.